# In C++ can you output a file to a user specified directory?

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream, user-defined

I'm just doing some work and the whole ofstream file("C:\mydir\blahblah\blah.txt") seems rather stiff.

Is there a way to let a user cin a directory?  Recently I've mastered having a user define the file name itself with the .c_str() so would it just be a level beyond that?  Or considering the newbie stage that I'm on, would it just be easier to be satisfied with hard coding the directory in? Either way it'll be interesting code to study from.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Are you asking the C++ equivalent of changing directory? You have to either hard code it, or allow the user to give it to you. You could obviously concatenate "directory name" with "file name" in code. Is that what you are asking about? Please clarify.

Comment: Using a `main` with argc and argv, you have the path to the executable itself and you can then append or subtract from this.

You might be interested in relative paths. If you are using something like the fstream library, you can pass relative paths to open and close functions:
`ifile.open("../common/text.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can let the user enter a directory. When you open the file, you just need to supply a string -- it makes no real difference whether it's hard-coded into the program, entered on the command line (and read from `argv`), or entered at run-time by the user.

Do note that if you do hard-code a directory name using back-slashes into the source code, you need to double each back-slash, so the name in the question should be `c:\\mydir\\blahblahblah\\blah.txt`.